# Does a connection to localhost go out onto the network?

Tags: networking

What I want to know is, if I were to execute something like `ping localhost`, would the packets be redirected by the operating system and go directly to the destination port or would the packets go out on the network to the nearest router or switch which then bounces them back to your computer?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415832/during-transmissions-over-localhost-which-layers-are-used-in-osi-model

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No packets will hit the network.  Unplug your network cable and try it!

Comment: IIRC, there was an older version of Windows where you didn't have a loopback interface if you didn't have a network interface.  It wouldn't work until your computer had been plugged into a network at least temporarily.  or something like that. silly windows.

Comment: I think Win 95 behaved that horrible way until you defined some kind of network interface. A dial-up adapter you never used was good enough.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is completely wrong and missleading. 127.0.0.1 is local IP and thus routed via table local, which means it's "in memory" operation and no network adapter is involved. Only not local IPs are being routed using the main routing table: serverfault.com/questions/683538/why-isnt-there-a-route-for-localhost-in-ubuntu

Comment: @JaroslavKucera: My answer says "No packets will hit the network."  You say "it's "in memory" operation and no network adapter is involved."  Those statements seem to agree, and yet you say "this answer is completely wrong and missleading."  Could you explain why it's wrong, please?

Comment: If by network you mean internal that packet only hits L4 layer inside the node, than yes, your answer is correct. Then I appologize... However the network usually means the environment outside the node (including HW NIC). And it isn't involved. Maybe would be good if you just modify your sentence to "No packets will hit the outside network."

Comment: I'm using the word "network" in the sense that it is used in the question.

Answer (score 14):

Any packets sent to an IP address attached to a local interface do not go out of your host.  127.0.0.1 is not special in this regard.  Both `ping 127.0.0.1` and `ping 192.168.1.44` will transmit and receive ICMP packets over the "loopback network device".  You can confirm this by unplugging your Ethernet cable and observing the TX and RX counters.

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet
          inet addr:192.168.1.44  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          RX packets:992670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:992670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
```

Answer (score 2):

The packets will stay on your machine.

The name 'localhost' is an alias from 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file, if you edit the hosts file (UNIX: /etc/hosts Windows: C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) and change localhost for any other word then you'll access your local host using that other word.

The address 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address, it is defined in [RFC3330](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's called loopback for a reason. IIRC, packets to 127.0.0.1 aren't allowed "outside" the computer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the packets will not go to the network.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on name resolution.
Try that ping after `# echo "69.59.196.211 localhost" > /etc/hosts`.